# responsive column is going below other column

Tags: html, css, html-email

I have been working a lot on 2 columns inside of a table with the foundation framework. I cannot understand why column 2 is going down under column 1, when I resize my window to under 600px? I would like that the columns are staying beside each other, when the window is resized. I have set the column to fill 6 each, so the second column should not jump down?

Does anybody knows how I can solve this? **The code is for email newsletter, that is why I am using tables**.

I have a JSfiddle with the CSS code aswell: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1ca6d4kt/2/)

```
<body>
  <table class="body">
    <tr>
      <td class="center" align="center" valign="top">
        <center>
            <table class="row footer">
                <tr>
                    <td class="wrapper">

                      <table class="six columns">
                        <tr>
                          <td class="left-text-pad">

                            <h5>Column 1</h5>

                            <table>
                              <tr>
                                <td>
                                  A content text 1
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>

                            <h5>A Headline</h5>

                            <table>
                              <tr>
                                <td>
                                  A content text 2
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>

                            <h5>A Headline</h5>

                            <table>
                              <tr>
                                <td>
                                  A content text 3
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                          <td class="expander"></td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                    <td class="wrapper">
                     <table class="six columns">
                        <tr>
                          <td class="left-text-pad">

                            <h5>Column 2</h5>

                            <table>
                              <tr>
                                <td>
                                  A content text 1
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>

                            <h5>A Headline</h5>

                            <table>
                              <tr>
                                <td>
                                  A content text 2
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>

                            <h5>A Headline</h5>

                            <table>
                              <tr>
                                <td>
                                  A big text to test if the text is responsive.
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                          <td class="expander"></td>
                        </tr>
                     </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </center>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: Stop using tables. Just stop.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to write it is for emails. So I am forced to use tables.

Comment: The code is wrong in many ways. Try to remove the tables and use `div` instead. You can't simply apply the foundation grid-classes to tables/rows.

Comment: Email clients are not supporting div tags. You can use div tags if you use the foundation for websites.

Comment: If it's for email why don't you use the foundation email framework? http://foundation.zurb.com/emails/docs/index.html

Comment: This is also foundation framework. The code is correct, except I need to change the column problem. This part of the code is from the Zurb team own template, so the code is correct. You can work with the CSS and the SASS version. This is the CSS version I am working with.

Comment: It is explicitly setting display:block for the wrappers: `@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) { table[class="body"] .wrapper { display: block !important; /* … */`

Comment: Should I set that to relative?

Comment: theres a bunch of stuff wrong here.. you're using a class `"six columns"`, it doesnt exist in the fiddle? theres stuff referencing `table.body` but you aren't using tables this way? This is making my head hurt! I would suggest making a cleaner example...

Comment: It is a direct copy of a template from the Zurb foundation company. So except they are coding their own language the wrong way, I cannot see then: http://foundation.zurb.com/emails/email-templates.html

Answer (score 1):

Above first wrapper class there is a  tag.So write style inside tr tag like

Answer (score 0):

Add `"float: left"` to the second wrapper of column2

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I just tried your solution, but it is not working unfortunately: http://vouzalis.com/test.html

Answer (score 0):

As of this writing, there is still use of the nested table layout for most email clients. The answer for this is simple: Not all clients are up to speed, not all computers are up to speed.

Using tables in html emails is the most practiced and best method for overall deployment regardless of your email client. Foundation is nice, yes - but it is not the email industry standard as of yet.

Take a look at [this handy tutorial](http://templates.mailchimp.com/development/html/) from Mailchimp. I just wanted to clarify that you are not wrong for doing it this way, and you will be better off learning responsive email coding from the aforementioned tutorials first.

All that being said - what you've done in your jsfiddle is actually correct. But if you do NOT want them to collapse, simply remove the `@media query` strings.